# Why is it called the "congruence class", not "congruence set"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic, terminology

Stupid question, why do we call it the congruence class, not congruence set?

Is there any scenario when the congruence class is not a set?

Comment: I like this question! Welcome to MSE!

Comment: We also speak of *equivalence classes*

Comment: I really don't know, but I would guess that it doesn't have much to do with the formal notion of a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)). From that article: "Outside set theory, the word "class" is sometimes used synonymously with "set". This usage dates from a historical period where classes and sets were not distinguished as they are in modern set-theoretic terminology.)"

Comment: Congruences in algebra were introduced by Gauss long before terms like “class” and “set” had a technical meaning as in set theory. Such terms for grouping related things together come from biology: class, order, family, and genus are all used as classifying labels in math.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for https://hsm.stackexchange.com . My best guess is that some influential author(s) early on used the word "class" in this context, and others simply took direction from them. I notice, for example, that Hardy and Wright give an italicized definition for a *class of residues* in their chapter on congruences. But this is pure speculation on my part.

Comment: The [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics pages](http://jeff560.tripod.com/c.html) has this entry: "CLASS (in set theory). In the early English literature the word *class* was used where *set* would be used today, e.g. in Bertrand Russell’s *Principles of Mathematics* (1903). Russell was following Peano. [...]" ... I don't know that this applies specifically to the "equivalence class" context, however. I agree that this question might be better-suited to [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If the reason is simply convention, the HSMSE would be best. If it’s because there’s a fundamental difference between a class and a set with regard to structure, which I think the second point is getting at, then MSE would be better. You almost have to already know the answer to make the call.

Comment: In german philosophy , congruence was defined as a similarity of forms , a qualitative similarity distinguished from equality or quantitative similarity. This may be the reason why number theory has used the term to denote a similarity between two numbers that is weaker than identity or equality , for example, the property of having the same remainder when divided by a given number. ( https://books.google.fr/books?id=oooN5uQ9O6cC&pg=PR69&dq=congruence+inauthor:kant&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjuhpTWhIrtAhUCzYUKHcEqDQIQ6AEwAnoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=congruence%20inauthor%3Akant&f=false)